# Pushing nested objects to next object in array [functional style]

Tags: javascript, lodash, ramda.js

I'm trying to get from an object that looks like this

```
[{current: [1], queue: []}, {current: [2], queue: []}, {current: [3], queue: []}]
```

to this:

```
[{current: [], queue: [3]}, {current: [], queue: [1]}, {current: [], queue: [2]}]
```

Basically, I want to push the item in "current" to the next item's queue.

I would like to use lodash or ramda.js to do this in the functional style. I'm quite new to functional style programming and I'm running into a wall with how to do this, especially handling the arr[2] -> arr[0] case. I thought about using a reduce but I'm not sure if that's the optimal way to solve the issue.

Comment: If the `current` array has more than one element does it move the first, last or all elements to the `queue` and does it add them to the beginning or end of the queue? Perhaps the example could be updated to demonstrate these scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`lodash#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to achieve this.

```
var result = array.map(function(value, index) {
  // get previous array value
  var prev = array[(index - 1 + array.length) % array.length];
  return Object.assign(
    {}, // Makes sure that we don't mutate the original array
    value, // retain properties that are not `current` and `queue`
    { current: prev.queue, queue: prev.current } // override
  );
});
```

```js
var array = [{
  current: [1],
  queue: []
}, {
  current: [2],
  queue: []
}, {
  current: [3],
  queue: []
}];

var result = array.map(function(value, index) {
  // get previous array value
  var prev = array[(index - 1 + array.length) % array.length];
  return Object.assign(
    {}, // Makes sure that we don't mutate the original array
    value, // retain properties that are not `current` and `queue`
    { current: prev.queue, queue: prev.current } // override
  );
});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Still have to iterate to change the property values which none of these solutions do

Comment: Also note that `slice()` will only shallow copy new array...but element object references will still be the same

Comment: You're right, didn't read the OP properly, I'll update it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

A fun ramda solution:

- Create a new array that prepends the last item (e.g.: `[1, 2, 3]` to `[3, 1, 2, 3]`)
- Use `aperture` to create pairs (e.g.: `[[3,1], [1,2], [2,3]]`)
- Use a merge function to make a new item from a pair (e.g.: `[4, 3, 5]`)

The `mergePair` and `loop` functions can probably be written differently... I couldn't find the right candidates in the docs.

```
const data = [{current: [1], queue: []}, {current: [2], queue: []}, {current: [3], queue: []}];

const mergePair = ([left, right]) => 
({ current: [], queue: concat(right.queue, left.current) })

const loop = arr => prepend(last(arr), arr);

const updateQueue = pipe(
  loop,
  aperture(2),
  map(mergePair)
)

updateQueue(data);
```

Try it **[here](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.24.1#?const%20data%20%3D%20%5B%7Bcurrent%3A%20%5B1%5D%2C%20queue%3A%20%5B%5D%7D%2C%20%7Bcurrent%3A%20%5B2%5D%2C%20queue%3A%20%5B%5D%7D%2C%20%7Bcurrent%3A%20%5B3%5D%2C%20queue%3A%20%5B%5D%7D%5D%3B%0A%0Aconst%20mergePair%20%3D%20%28%5Bleft%2C%20right%5D%29%20%3D%3E%20%0A%28%7B%20current%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%20queue%3A%20concat%28right.queue%2C%20left.current%29%20%7D%29%0A%0Aconst%20loop%20%3D%20arr%20%3D%3E%20prepend%28last%28arr%29%2C%20arr%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20updateQueue%20%3D%20pipe%28%0A%20%20loop%2C%0A%20%20aperture%282%29%2C%0A%20%20map%28mergePair%29%0A%29%0A%0AupdateQueue%28data%29%3B)**

Answer (score -1):

One simple way is make a deep copy and move last item to first position in that copy.

Then iterate original to update each queue to matching index in rearranged copy

```js
var data = [{current: [1], queue: []}, {current: [2], queue: []}, {current: [3], queue: []}],
    // make a copy of array
    copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    // move last to first in copy
    copy.unshift(copy.pop());


data.forEach((el,i)=> {
  el.queue = copy[i].current;
  el.current.length = 0;  
});

console.log(data)
```